# Which algebraic expression is correct 1 or 2? or both are wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]
[image]

I think the second equation is wrong. Cause, that should be

$$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{mk}{l^2}(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}} cos(\theta'-\theta))\tag{1}$$
Or,
$$-\frac{1}{r}=\frac{mk}{l^2}(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}} cos(\theta-\theta'))\tag{2}$$

It's simple math I don't think I missed anything.

My attempt :

$$-\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{El^2}{mk^2}}}=\cos(\theta-\theta')$$

Wrong?

$$-\frac{l^2u}{mk}+1=\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}\cos(\theta-\theta')$$

Then simple.

Comment: I would write $\arccos(\dots)=\theta'-\theta$, then $(\dots)=\cos(\theta'-\theta)$ and so on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I also chose it but looking further if I could matched with the book's equation.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you follow the steps I wrote, you get what's in the book, after you notice that $\cos(\theta'-\theta)=\cos(\theta-\theta')$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first expression, the second expression follows. In the first step of your solution, you make a mistake with a minus sign. Note that your expression (1) is actually equivalent to expression 3.55 in the book. This follows from the equation $\cos(z)=\cos(-z)$ for all $z$, which implies that $\cos(\theta-\theta')=\cos(\theta'-\theta)$.

I shall give a derivation of expression 3.55:
The first expression in the book implies that $$\theta-\theta'=-\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right).$$
Taking the cosine of both sides, we obtain that
$$\cos(\theta-\theta')=\cos\left(-\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right)\right).$$
Using the equation $\cos(z)=\cos(-z)$ for the right-hand side, we see that

$$\cos(\theta-\theta')=\cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right)\right).$$
Therefore,
$$\cos(\theta-\theta')=\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}.$$
Next, we obtain that
$$\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1=\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}\cos(\theta-\theta').$$
As you said, the rest is simple.

Comment: You wrote that $\cos(z)=\cos(-z)$ But I think it depends on axis, doesn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by axis?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oops! I meant to say Quadrant.. In first Quadrant cos is positive. It is negative in second and third, isn't it?

Comment: The equation $\cos(z)=\cos(-z)$ holds for all $z\in\mathbb C$. This follows from the taylor series $\cos(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i)!}z^{2i}$. From this we see that $\cos(-z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i)!}(-z)^{2i}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i)!}((-z)^2)^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i)!}(z^2)^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i)!}z^{2i}=\cos(z)$.

Comment: The cosine is an even function, Istiak. Have you never looked at its graph? Symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis, isn't it?